# logrotate advanced date in daily rotations

Tags: logrotate, sles

I have set a logrotate config file like this:

```
/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out{
copytruncate
daily
dateext
rotate 10
missingok
notifempty
}
```

And in my /sysconfig/cron settings file I have set `DAILY_TIME="00:00"`
It rotates the logs but if a log has the date `catalina.out-20150415` it contains log info from date 20150414, this is one day before.

Should I change the date in the /sysconfig/cron file or maybe I could achive this with the prerotate/endscript option?

As far as I know DAILY_TIME works in 15minute gaps and I would like to have as perfet daily logs that contain just the information of one day as possible. What is what I get now, but the date in the name of the files does not adhere to the contents within them.

Note: I am under SLES, where [daily cron jobs](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/why-are-my-cron-jobs-not-running-when-expected/) work a bit different from other distros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't play with /sysconfig/cron, other than set the daily cronjobs at midnight, and prefer postrotate instead.

Let's suppose today is 17/04/2015, this is the content of your directory after the rotation but before postrotate script has run:

```
catalina.out-20150414
catalina.out-20150415
catalina.out-20150417
catalina.out
```

Note that `catalina.out-20150416` is missing as 1) the last log file created by the rotation is named `catalina.out-20150417` and 2) the log that was created yesterday has been renamed to `catalina.out-20150415` to reflect its content.

This scenario allows us to do a "blind renaming" of today log with the date of yesterday, like:

```
...
postrotate
    mv "catalina.out-$(date +"%Y%m%d")" "catalina.out-$(date --date="yesterday" +"%Y%m%d")" > /dev/null 2>&1 || true
endscript
...
```

In case of missing log files `mv` will raise an error message that is redirected to `/dev/null` and a positive return value is ensured by `|| true`

Comment: I touchted /sysconfig/cront to set the time for the logrotate tasks to run. Its default value is empty, so no problem to change it again. Otherwise I would have to delete cron.daily at a time near the time I want logrotate daily tasks to run.
About your solution, mind that notifempty is in the logrotate, so gap names are expected.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I wouldn't tweak and play with it to achieve the behavior you desire. Moving the daily jobs at midnight is kind of "standard procedure". I too in my servers run the daily jobs at midnight.
If there's a gap in file naming nothing happens, simply no file is renamed by mv and its stderr is redirected to /dev/null. I'll clarify "gap names" in the answer

Comment: I finally adopted a solution close to @ColOfAbRiX's, but a bit more applicable/scalable to any future/past date:
`mv "catalina.out-$(date +"%Y%m%d")" "catalina.out-$(date -d "-1 days" +"%Y%m%d")" > /dev/null 2>&1 || true`

Comment: Well, after trying I get `mv: cannot stat 'catalina.out-20150517': No such file or directory`
I set the DAILY_TIME="00:00" in /etc/sysconfig/cron and the date of my catalina.out-20150517 file is 0:00:01, so I don't understand why it gets that error after rotating the file if the time of the file has already the same day as the day the postrotate is running.

Comment: It was my bad, I was missing the absolute path of my catalina.out-YYYYMMDD file, so the correct way would be: 
`mv "/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out-$(date +"%Y%m%d")" "/var/log/tomcat/catalina.out-$(date -d "-1 days" +"%Y%m%d")" > /dev/null 2>&1 || true`

Answer (score 0):

Running into this issue as well, but wanted to note that if you're using a directory and wildcard as part of the log name definition (e.g. /var/log/*.log) which matches several log files, postrotate needs a non-hard-coded log to move.

The solution I found is postrotate uses $1 as the argument of the logname, so you can do:

```
/var/log/mylog*.log
    dateext
    dateformat .%Y%m%d
    ...
    # Content of the rotated log is from the previous day
    postrotate
        today=$(date +%Y%m%d)
        yesterday=$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y%m%d)
        mv $1.$today $1.$yesterday
    endscript
```